# git cannot open the .gitconfig file although it exists

Tags: git, config, global, backslash

I am using git inside visual studio. Unfortunately `config --global` information cannot be accessed or edited. It seems that git is using the string `'%USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig'` and failing where if it where to use `'%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig'` it would succeed as the file exists and is healthy.

How do I modify my setup so that git can find this `.gitconfig` file.

The following command line data conforms the basic nature of the fault

```
C:\Users\xxxxxx\source\repos\yyyyyy>git --version
git version 2.37.1.windows.1

C:\Users\xxxxxx\source\repos\yyyyyy>git.exe config --global --list
fatal: unable to read config file '%USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig': No such file or directory

C:\Users\xxxxxx\source\repos\yyyyyy>dir "%USERPROFILE%/.gitconfig"
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0AA3-F60F

 Directory of C:\Users\xxxxxx

File Not Found

C:\Users\xxxxxx\source\repos\yyyyyy>dir "%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig"
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0AA3-F60F

 Directory of C:\Users\xxxxxx

04/10/2021  22:11               501 .gitconfig
               1 File(s)            501 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  1,070,514,884,608 bytes free
```

Comment: Git it a bit finicky with file permissions, which might be an issue here. Copy the file to your Desktop (temp), delete it in its original location. Then run the commands again. Git should create you a file with the correct permissions. Then copy **the contents** of your old config file into the other.